Geo nodes, is it possibble to make a transparent planes with objects on it?
Is it possible to create a transparent plane on which the cubes lie?
I have worked with GeoNodes.
Thanks in advance for your help!


update file:


What kind of transparency are you looking for? A glass like transparency? Invisible plane, but it conceals the bottoms of the cubes? A transparency that tints everything underneath it a different color?

Hi! I invisible plane!

I just want the cubes to be shown

You can just disconnect the base geometry (a.k.a. the plane) from the Join Geometry node. Unless you are going to be using the plane. I'll post an answer for more info.

For an invisible plane, you could simply disconnect the plane's geometry from the Join Geometry node. As in:
Before:
After:
Notice that the green line is no longer bridging between the Group Input and the Join Geometry.
If you are going to be using the plane (or it's properties), make a material that is completely invisible. Since you are using cycles, it is quite simple.
Create a material, and name it anything you would like.
Under the material's Principled BSDF, set the Alpha value to 0.

In your Geometry Node setup, create a Set Material node.
Connect the Group Input's Geometry output to the Set Material node.
In the Set Material node, select the Transparent material created earlier.
Connect the Set Material node to the Join Geometry node.
The method I listed above only works for Cycles, so you need to be in rendered view. If you want to see the results in the Material view or EEVEE, follow these steps:
Switch the render engine to EEVEE. Under the transparency material, and then under the Settings, set the Blend mode to anything but Opaque. Hope this helps! Also, you can switch back to Cycles render engine if you'd like.
Also, here's the file: 

Thank you for taking the time to help me, I appreciate it.
Since I need the properties of the plane, I tried your second method. But I can't get it to work. What could I be doing wrong? I have re-uploaded the file, with your solution. I added the address in the original post.

@N03 Oh sorry! I forgot to mention that you need to disconnect the original Geometry. Or you could insert it between the two nodes. I'll upload the file so you can just use that.
